# wxwidgets event at specific time

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to check system time and if the time is right (i think the right time has passed during some interval ago would be more correct) make certain actions using wxwidgets.
I haven't found a specific class or event that can handle such conditions (I know there is wxTimer widget but it is timer - it counts time since some moment but not checks it)
Is there a better way than having a thread that just runs a `while(true)` loop checking system time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the wxTimer class *generates an event* when the duration has elapsed:
[wxTimerEvent documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer_event.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the boost::asio deadline timer for this.

```
void handler(boost::system::error_code ec) { ... }
...
io_service i;
...
deadline_timer t(i);
t.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(400));
t.async_wait(handler);
...
i.run();
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/timers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wxTimer` to perform an action at some point in the future, just start it with the interval equal to the difference between this point and now (`wxDateTime` can help you with that).